# In eclipse, republish doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, xslt

I do most of my web development in XSL/JS. Up til now, I was able to change any .xsl file, the server would republish the resources and next time I refreshed that page on my browser, I'd be able to see the changes. Now I have to restart the server every time I want to see a change after modifying an xsl file.

Things I've tried:

- Build Automatically is ON
- Automatically republish when resources change is selected
- Clearing my browser cache
- Manually clicking "republish" on my server.
- Cleaning Tomcat
- Cleaning the work directory
- Removing and adding the project on the server

Using tomcat 6.0 in Eclipse Juno

Comment: Try right-clicking the Tomcat server in the "Servers" view and choosing "Clean Working Directory".

Comment: Tried doing that, and cleaning the server, and removing/adding the project from the server